# Process large files from S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to get a large file (>10gb) on s3 (stored as csv on s3) and send it as a csv in the response header. I am doing it by using the following procedure:

```
async getS3Object(params:any) {

        s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Error Fetching File');
            }
            else {
                const csv = data.Body.toString('utf-8');
                res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${fileId}.csv`);
                res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
                res.status(200).send(csv);
            }
          });
```

This is taking painfully long to process the file and send it as a csv attachments. How can I make this faster?

Comment: You could just redirect directly to S3, letting the user download directly.  If needed, you could use a presigned URL that recreates the content disposition and content type in addition to providing access.

Comment: Presigned url works great but I really want to build this as an api, when invoked, returns a csv file as response

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a *huge* file; you could break that into chunks using [range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36436057/s3-how-to-do-a-partial-read-seek-without-downloading-the-complete-file) (see also the [docs, search for "calling the getobject property"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property)). If you need the whole file, you could split the work off into [workers](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), though at some point the limit will probably be your connection, and if you need to send the whole file as an attachment that won't help much.

A better solution would be to never download the file in the first place. You can do this by [streaming from S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782434/streaming-file-from-s3-with-express-including-information-on-length-and-filetype) ([see also this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70625366/streaming-files-from-aws-s3-with-nodejs), [and this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366381/aws-s3-v3-javascript-sdk-stream-file-from-bucket-getobjectcommand)), or setting up a [proxy in your server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-proxy) so the bucket/subdir seems to the client to be in your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this on EC2, the network performance of the EC2 instances varies based on the EC2 type and size. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-network-bandwidth.html

A bottleneck can happen at multiple places:

- Network (bandwidth and latency)
- CPU
- Memory
- Local Storage

One can check each of these. CloudWatch Metrics is our friend here.

CPU is the easiest to see and to scale with a bigger instance size.

Memory is a bit harder to observe, but one should have enough memory to keep the document in memory, so the OS does not use the swap.

Local Storage - IO can be observed; If the business logic is just to parse a csv file and output the result in, let's say, another S3 bucket, and there is no need to save the file locally - EC2 instances with local storage can be used - https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ - Storage Optimized.

Network - EC2 instance size can be modified, or Network optimized instances can be used.

Network - the way that one connects to S3 matters. Usually, the best approach is the use an S3 VPC endpoint https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html. The gateway option is free to use. By adopting it, one eliminates the VPC NAT gateway/NAT instance limitations, and it's even more secure.

Network - Sometimes, the S3 is in one region, and the compute is in another. S3 support replication https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html

Maybe some type of APM monitoring and code instrumentation can show is the code can also be optimized.

Thank you.